# Поиск значения по двум условиям

Tags: excel

Мне надо, чтобы был поиск значения по двум условиям. 
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня будет таблица, состоящая из `Color` и `Type of wire`. Формула, сравнивая эти значения, должна определять `Number`. Номеров около тысячи, поэтому думаю, как реализовать поиск по этому условию.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сцепить эти колонки и получить уникальное значение и по нему осуществлять поиск. сцепить(COLOR;Type of wire) получаем BKFLY 10.00 QMM уникальное зачение после переместив колонку Number в право от уникального значения осуществляем ВПР(искомое значение то есть BKFLY 10.00 QMM;диапазон поиска;2;0)

```
        A                      B                C                 D
    уникальное значение  Number           искомое значение

 1. BKFLY 10.00 QMM       P00143562      сюда подставляете    формула с ВПР
                                             значение        выводит Number
 2.  ------                -------          
 3.  ------                -------
 4. ------                 -------
 5.  ------               --------
```

Так выглядит формула:
=ВПР(С1;A1:B5;2;0)

Comment: Большое спасибо))

Answer (score 2):

```
=ИНДЕКС(A1:A4;МИН(ЕСЛИ(B2:B4=E2;ЕСЛИ(C2:C4=F2;СТРОКА(B2:B4)))))
```

Формула массива вводится тремя клавишами: *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* (формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками).
С помощью функций *ЕСЛИ* исключаются лишние вычисления.

Если предварительно объединить значения, формула упрощается и не требует "массивного" ввода:

```
=ИНДЕКС(A2:A4;ПОИСКПОЗ(F2&G2;D2:D4;))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если сцепку *Color&Type* переместить левее таблицы (в столбец *A*, сама таблица сместится на один столбец вправо), можно применить формулу с единственной функцией *ВПР*:

```
=ВПР(F2&G2;A2:D4;2;)
```

' ---------------

Функция пользователя (UDF)

```
Function FindIf(r1 As Range, r2 As Range)
Dim a()
Dim lRws As Long
Dim i As Long
    lRws = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    a = Range("A1:C" & lRws).Value

    For i = 2 To lRws
        If a(i, 2) = r1.Value Then
            If a(i, 3) = r2.Value Then
                FindIf = a(i, 1): Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    FindIf = "Not"
End Function
```

Функция размещается в общем модуле. Макросы должны быть разрешены. В ячейку листа:

```
=FindIf(F2;G2)
```

где *F2* и *G2* - ячейки выбора прараметров.

Answer (score 0):

Так понимаю, вам необходима логическая операция `И`

Реализуется так:

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(B2=0, C2=0));"ИСТИНА";"ЛОЖЬ"
```

Почитать про логические выражения в Excel можно [тут](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-294d9486-b332-48ed-b489-abe7d0f9eda9?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU#ID0EAABAAA=Logical)

Comment: Это невозможно скормить функции ВПР() - не поймёт...